# How to change the default command scope in the Felix gogo shell?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

When you enter a command into the gogo shell, it looks first in the default scope for a match for that command.  How do you configure what this default scope is?

For example, if you start up the Felix framework with gogo, it uses the `felix` scope as the default.  But if you start up equinox 3.8.1, which now uses the felix shell as the default, it uses the `equinox` scope as default.

The main irritation is that when I type:

```
g! help
```

I get the results from `equinox:help`, instead of `felix:help`, so I'd like to make the `felix` scope the default.

Is there an OSGi framework property to configure this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not specified anywhere _how_ this search occurs, except that the _first_ command found gets executed. This is also not part of OSGi specs unfortunately, so there is no detailed docs about this stuff either. I guess this is what happens when everyone starts making up their own standards. You can file a bug for this with felix project here: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/Felix  I think they are relatively responsive.

Comment: Are you using SSH or Telnet to connect to the gogo shell, even transparently? Looks like here, equinox defaults to using EQUINOX_SCOPE by default.

https://github.com/eclipse/rt.equinox.bundles/search?q=EQUINOX_SCOPE&type=Code

Patching the bundle seems simple enough, but it looks like could be a limitation in how equinox uses the felix CommandSession in both of those, not providing a configurable way to use default scope.

Answer (score 3):

The gogo shell, when starting up, will try to find a startup script. By default it will look in the folder (relative to your startup directory):

```
etc/gosh_profile
```

If it does not find a script there, the default script (inside org.apache.felix.gogo.shell) is used, which contains this line:

```
SCOPE = gogo:*
```

So, to change the default scope, provide your own script.